# Ajax cascading dropdownlist web method in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have been practicing with the online tutorial on how to do this except my dropdownlist just gets a "method error 500" in the dropdownlist. I have found a few topics on this and have tried to fix this myself but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error earlier this morning and rectified it. What I have done is, I just created a web method in the XXXXXX.aspx.cs as following

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetRoomsDetails(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
{
    WebService1 cs = new WebService1();
    return cs.GetRooms(knownCategoryValues, category);
}
```

Do it for all the web methods in your YYYY.asmx.cs. Now, go to the XXXXXX.aspx page and make changes as below:

ServiceMethod="GetRoomsDetails" and remove the servicepath property for the CascadeDropdown that is associated with Rooms dropdown. Repeat the same for all the dropdowns respectively with their method names.

This is working for me.

Please let me know if its still having issue. Next time, provide all the code so that I can figure out the issue...

Regards,
Vamsi Anil
mvamsianil@gmail.com

Comment: thanks for the response although your way probably works in my case i simply forgot the  <WebMethod()> _ at the top of each function which was causing the error. Thanks again for your help